# Java - stuck and confused with if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, numbers

I'm a bit stuck. I want my program to accept 0 and non 0 numbers, but if that non 0 number is above or below a certain integer, it will not work. Hopefully that makes sense.

Here's what I have:

```
    if (pos != 0 || pos == 0)
    {

        System.out.println ("\nLength of int: " + len);
        System.out.println ("Position from right: " + pos);
        System.out.println ("Number selected: " + String.valueOf (nums).charAt (s));

    }

    else if (pos < len || pos > len)
    {
        System.out.println ("\n0");

    }
```

If anyone wants to see the full code, it's right here: http://pastebin.com/bFVYNhvr

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `pos != 0 || pos == 0` [is always true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle)

Comment: `pos` is an `int` - as it stands it can accept `0` and `non-0` numbers

Answer (score 2):

change your logic around the other way

```
if (pos < len || pos > len)
{
    System.out.println ("\n0");
}
else 
{
    System.out.println ("\nLength of int: " + len);
    System.out.println ("Position from right: " + pos);
    System.out.println ("Number selected: " + String.valueOf (nums).charAt (s));
}
```

As @Vinod mentioned

```
if (pos < len || pos > len)
```

can be better written as

```
if (pos != len)
```

if that is indeed your intention